# Calling functions from `coffee` executable

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, textmate, read-eval-print-loop

Forgive the noob question, but why is it that I can't call (almost) any standard functions from the `coffee` REPL (or from files written and run within TextMate, for that matter)?

Variable assignment works, functions don't.

Examples:

```
coffee> string = "string"
'string'
coffee> list = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
coffee> num = 42
42
coffee> opposite = true
true
coffee> num = -42 if opposite
-42
```

but

```
coffee> alert "Hello, World"
ReferenceError: alert is not defined
    at repl:1:5
    at REPLServer.replDefaults.eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:33:28)
    at repl.js:239:12
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:62:9)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

and

```
coffee> print "Hello"
ReferenceError: print is not defined
    at repl:1:5
    at REPLServer.replDefaults.eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:33:28)
    at repl.js:239:12
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:62:9)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

What really gets me is:

```
coffee> console.log "Help!"
Help!
undefined
```

I have Node installed via Homebrew and CoffeeScript installed (globally) via `npm`.

Comment: When using `node`, `console.log` is the normal way to get output.  You can define `print=console.log` if you prefer to use that name.  `console.log` does print, or show, what you want.  But it also returns `undefined`.  But you won't see that when used in a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alert` is not a *feature* of javascript.  It's part of the API the browser *exposes* to JavaScript.  And `coffee` at the command line on you computer is just a thin wrapper around `node.js` that translated coffee script into javascript to be interpreted by node.  `node.js` does not provide an `alert` function.  Nor does it provide a global `print` function.

Both node, and the browser, do provide a `console` object globally.  So `console.log` works the same.

Brush up on the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/) to learn what function node exposes.  And rememebr that just because it works in a browser does not mean it will work in node.

Comment: Then why is that every CoffeeScript tutorial I read uses `alert` as though it were something you could just call? I don't ask that to be snarky, I'm just confused by it.

Comment: Because you are intended to run that coffee script, compiled to JS, in your browser.  And as long as you have a browser running it, it's an easy way to see a value.

Comment: For now, I'd stick to running it in your browser.  Node.js (even via the `coffee` command) is a bit more complex for a lot of reasons.  I'd also recommend learning basic javascript before jumping into coffeescript.

Comment: hpaulj thats because its run through the browser

Answer (score 1):

`alert` and `print` are not native `node.js` functions

If you want to get started at the command line with coffee without making changes to example code snippets try the following two assignments at the prompt before running your code.

`print = console.log`
`alert = console.log`

Here is a small Hello World function to get you started:-

`coffee> hello = (word) -> console.log "Hello " + word`
`coffee> hello "World"`
`Hello World`

Answer (score 0):

before you use 'alert' command

1. must install 'alert-node' lib
2. require 'alert-node' to your script

follow in this link ->
[Alert function not working in coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389540/alert-function-not-working-in-coffeescript)

```js
npm install alert-node

alert = require('alert-node')
```