# Alert function not working in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, syntax-error, alert

I found about CoffeeScript in a blog and decided to give it a try ,my first project/code with it was this

```
alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"
```

It doesn't work and gives this reply

```
ReferenceError: alert is not defined
```

is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you executing that…? In a browser?

Comment: Are you sure you're using coffeescript? You can't just write it as code and run it in the browser like javascript.

Comment: Nope in my os (windows) on my cmd

Comment: What does _"in my os"_ mean?

Comment: Try `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: i am not executing it on my browser

Comment: Did you installed nodejs also?

Comment: Yeah npm and node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a language which is strongly tied to the concept of **environments**. A **browser** and **Node.js** are two possible environments to run JS code (CoffeeScript compiles to JavaScript).

When JavaScript is embedded in a browser, the global object is `window`. But in Node.js, the global object is simply `global`.

Some methods are available in both environments, like core JavaScript methods...

- `String.prototype` methods
- `Array.prototype` methods
- `Object.prototype` methods
- etc.

... and specific `window` methods like `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

However, `window.alert` is obviously not available in CLI. If you want this functionality in Node, you will have to use something like [alert-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alert-node) ---> `npm i alert-node`.

### JavaScript

```
// alert.js
var alert = require('alert-node');
alert('Hello');
```

*Command:* `node alert.js`

### CoffeeScript

```
# alert.coffee
alert = require 'alert-node'
alert 'Hello'
```

*Command:* `coffee alert.coffee`

Answer (score 2):

[`window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is a method defined by the DOM (in browsers), not by Javascript. If the environment you're running this in doesn't have a global `alert` method defined, then you can't call it.